# Node WS accessing object data on received message

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, websocket, ws

Following the standard example from the NodeJS 'ws' package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

```
import WebSocket from 'ws';

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path');

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('something');
});

ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  console.log('received: %s', data);
});
```

I am wondering how to do anything with the data that I receive on the `on.('message')` method. The returned data looks like it is somehow encoded (Arraybuffered?):

`console.log(data)` produces: `<Buffer 7b 22 6b 65 65 70 41 6c 69 76 65 22 3a 22 31 22 7d>`

`console.log(data.toString())` produces: `{"keepAlive":"1"}`

. How do I go about converting this data into an object, where the keys would be accessible? e.g.:

```
ws.on('message', function message(data) {

  //Some conversion needs to happen here

  if(data.thatKey){
    doThis();
  }
});
```

`.toString()`seems to correctly convert the data into a readable string, but this string can't be parsed back into an object. I have also tried `JSON.stringify()` and then `JSON.parse()` but this also produces a string that cannot be converted into an object.

I have also tried something like this:

```
function ab2str(buf) {
        return decoder.decode(new Uint8Array(buf));
}
```

Which also returns a string that cannot be converted into an object (it seems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a string of text (in this case json) and you should `var obj = JSON.parse(data)`

which in case of your data would look like:

```js
// console.log(data.toString()) produces: {"keepAlive":"1"}
var data = `{"keepAlive":"1"}`;
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I am not getting a string passed to me. I am getting this: ```<Buffer 7b 22 6b 65 65 70 41 6c 69 76 65 22 3a 22 31 22 7d>```, which seems to be information that has been buffered into an array. If i ```.toString()``` that, I get a string that looks like an object. This cannot be converted into an object again using ```JSON.parse()```, unfortunately.

Comment: why not? what is the output or error of `JSON.parse(data.toString())`?

Comment: I was getting the standard 
`"SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"`
error when I attempted this - but I realized that the first `ws.send('something');` call in the `on.('open')` method is actually treated as a message on the server as well, which was why it didn't work. So, your solution is in fact (of course) correct.